# Computing the Shapley Value for this two-player game

Tags: solution-verification, game-theory

It is well known that the Shapley Value for any player $i\in N$ in any game $v:2^N\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by the following formula:
\begin{gather}
S_i(\nu)=\sum_{S\subseteq N\backslash\{i\}}\frac{|S|!\times[|N|-|S|-1]!}{|N|!}\times[\nu(S\cup\{i\})-\nu(S)]
\end{gather}

Consider the following two-player game: $\nu(\{i,j\})=1,\nu(\{i\})=0,\nu(\{j\})=-1$. It is straightforward to see that the $S_i(\nu)=1$ and $S_j(\nu)=0$. However, applying the formula above for player $i$ yields:
\begin{align}
S_i(\nu)&=\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[1-(-1)]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times2\\
&=1
\end{align}

And for player $j$, applying the formula yields:
\begin{align}
S_j(\nu)&=\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[1-0]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

It is obvious to me that I'm not understanding the formula above and I am thus not applying it correctly. Can anybody please spot and explain my mistake?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me more time than expected, but I finally figured it out myself. Instead of deleting the question, I post here the answer because it may help others in the future.

The error in my reasoning is the omission of the emptyset. It is generally assumed that $\nu(\{\emptyset\})=0$. Therefore, the correct way to apply the formula above is as follows. For player $i$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_i(\nu)&=\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[1-(-1)]+\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[0-0]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times2+\frac{1}{2}\times0\\
&=1
\end{align}

Applying the formula for player $j$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_j(\nu)&=\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[1-0]+\frac{1!\times0!}{2!}\times[0-1]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times1+\frac{1}{2}\times(-1)\\
&=0
\end{align}

Hence, $\mathcal{S}_i(\nu)=1$ and $\mathcal{S}_j(\nu)=0$. And we're done!